# Система управления файлами на языке Go

Tags: golang, mongodb, rest

Мне нужно написать REST-интерфейс для приложения, которое работает с большими файлами, но показались подводные камни, которые я вначале не предвидел.

Рест-интерфейс включает такие эндпоинты:

- create, создает пустой файл с заданным именем и возвращает его временный ID
- append, получает ID и имя файла, дописывает байты в конец файла и возвращает временный id
- commit, получает временный ид файла и заливает файл в удаленную MongoDB (GridFS)

Похоже, мне нужна какая-то библиотека для упрвления локальными файлами, которая поддерживает список созданных файлов, позволяет искать файлы по имени и ID и обновлять содержимое. Как это можно сделать на языке Go?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве такой библиотеки может выступать та же монга, если нагрузка позволяет.

Либо использовать встроенные базы вроде BoltDB https://github.com/boltdb/bolt

Обновлять содержимое можно штатными средствами.

Создавать файл - через os.OpenFile или ioutil.WriteFile() c пустым содержимым.

Открыть файл для добавления содержимого можно через os.OpenFile с флагом os.O_APPEND. Там же через флаги можно задавать должен ли файл быть создан при его отсутствии и т.п.